# 404 error when adding a different route - Laravel dead simple routing

Tags: php, laravel

I've been laraveling for 5 months now but I reformatted ubuntu and installed Laravel, this time, it's Laravel 7 instead of Laravel 6. My problem is simple routing giving an error. It's so dead simple you might think I'm a stupid beginner.

In my **Web.php**

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I also tried using a controller that returns a `view` and just a simple `"string"` in **Web.php**

```
Route::get('/about', 'UserController@index');
```

Typing `http://localhost/about` in the address bar in chrome causes 404 error. 
As you can see, there should be no problem returning the same `view('welcome')`, even if I return a simple `return "TEST";`, results are the same.

I tried downgrading to Laravel 6 by deleting `vendor`, changing the Laravel v6 in `composer.json` and running `composer install` but still the same, so I think it's not the version.

This has never happened to me before even when I first started with Laravel 6 five months ago and it's a totally fresh project.

Comment: Does `php artisan route:list` reveal anything unusual? What server are you using?

Comment: does rewrite_module active in you web server?

Comment: have you run your server with `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: Could be a different server running on `http://localhost`. If you run `php  artisan serve` in your fresh project, it tells you which server:post to use, this should use `http://localhost:8000` by default. See if navigating to `http://localhost:8000/about` fixes your problem

Comment: Does php artisan route:list and send outout in comment

Comment: First start your server by running the php artisan serve and then check with the generated url in the browser.

Comment: @kerbholz, I'm getting permission issues when ```php artisan route:list```, but it works
if I ```sudo php artisan route:list``` and can see my ```/``` route and ```/about``` route just fine. 
Owner and Group of the project is $USER:$USER so I shouldn't be getting permission if i just run without ```sudo```

Comment: @Deepak, I use Apache2. Not sure if this is correct and I'm new to these module thing but
I checked using ```apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES```, ```apachectl -M```, but i did not see anything close to the word "rewrite".
But thanks for the hint, I tried ```sudo a2enmod rewrite``` seeing that it is missing and it's now working. Thanks a ton! 
I can't remember enabling rewrite before i reformatted my ubuntu but I must have. 
Would you care to tell me more about that problem or point me to a good resource? 
I didn't fully understand it. I'll check around too just to confirm my understanding.

Comment: @Mahmud hasan, no, I'm using Apache2. I tried using ```php artisan serve``` and everything works fine. 
I stopped apache2 and ```sudo a2dismod rewrite``` just to make sure that it's not apache2 that's serving my site.

Comment: Thanks guys, everything works now. 
I tested ```php artisan serve``` out of curiosity and it works fine. 
It was the rewrite_module that was missing in my apache2 server

Comment: @ShuPesmerga so in general php and apache server render URL based on the files available in folder or in file system. However by using rewrite_module, apache server gets additional ability to server those urls actually does not exists in file structure or they have been created dynamically. Laravel creates url dynamically at run time hence we need rewrite_module to create and redirect them at correct location. You can visit apache and php official sites for detailed information. I am submitting the answer in Answer section so others can you this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable `rewrite_mode` of Apache server and restart Apache server it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run server with php artisan serve
and then try http://localhost:8000/about hope it will fix your problem

OR
Simply use http://localhost/project/about